# Typescript interface issue

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand interfaces in typescript.The current code is throwing an error

`Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'myObj': userId, title, id`

As i understand, `fetchDetails` function should return a value of type `Promise<myObj>`, but since `data` is of type `Response`. It is giving me error. But i don't want to use any extra variable inside the function, how can i return the required response ?

```
interface myObj {
  userId:number,
  title:string,
  id:string,
  body:string
}[]
 
async function fetchDetails(url:string):Promise<myObj>{
  let data:Response = await fetch(url);
  data = await data.json();
  return data;
}
fetchDetails('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the data directly or assign it to a different variable name. It's going to be like the following:

```js
interface myObj {
  userId:number,
  title:string,
  id:string,
  body:string
}[]
 
async function fetchDetails(url:string):Promise<myObj>{
  const response:Response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
fetchDetails('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

Comment: What if i don't want to use 2 variables inside `fetchDetails` function ?

Comment: You can force the result to be of your type with type assertion: `return data as unknown as myObj;`